# How to add elements to GridBagLayout from paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, gridbaglayout

In the following code, in the constructor the label gets correctly created and displayed on the screen. Note that it is added to the `GridBagLayout()` layout manager. Then, in the `paintComponent()` method that we override from the JPanel extention, we reset the contents of the JPanel and add the label again. However, this time the label is not displayed on the screen. I would expect it to be added normally, but it is not. Why is this the case?

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private final GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();

    public MyPanel () {
        setBounds(200, 200, 1000, 1000);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setOpaque(false);
        setVisible(false);

        grid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;

        JLabel oldLabel = new JLabel("This is an old Label");
        add(oldLabel, grid);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        removeAll();

        JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("This is a new Label");
        add(newLabel, grid);

        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

In this example the component is known, but in my situation I have a variable amount of components that is not known beforehand and changes during the program.

Comment: The creation of new Swing or AWT elements is not allowed in the function `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. The function is constantly called to update all elements after a `repaint` call.

Comment: **Under no circumstances** should a paintComponent create, add, or remove components.  Painting is triggered by the system, for many many reasons, including seemingly trivial events like moving the mouse over the window.  Also, never call `repaint` from a paintComponent method;  that forces Swing to eventually called paintComponent again, which means you have created an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. If you can't add components to a paintComponent() how would you display them? In my example the component is known, but in my situation I have a variable amount of components that is not known beforehand and changes during the program. (I will edit the question to refine it)

Comment: *and changes during the program* - so then you add the components to the panel and invoke `revalidate()` on the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments to my question kindly say, my approach is not correct.

**Under no circumstances** should a `paintComponent` create, add, or remove components. Painting is triggered by the system, for many many reasons, including seemingly trivial events like moving the mouse over the window. Also, never call `repaint` from a paintComponent method; that forces Swing to eventually called paintComponent again, which means you have created an infinite loop.

The solution is to add the components to the panel and invoke `revalidate()` on the panel instead.